# SQL Server 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.' when inserting date values from WinForm DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I'm trying to insert date value from `DateTimePicker` element in WinForms to a user defined method in the Table Adapter.

This is the function that gets data from the `DateTimePicker` element and inserts into the user defined method in the Table Adapter.

```
    private void btn_searchRooms_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string checkIn = dtPicker_checkIn.Value.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd");
        string checkOut = dtPicker_checkOut.Value.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd");

        var dt = roomsTableAdapter.GetAvailableRooms(checkIn, checkOut);

        dtGridView_availableRooms.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

This is the user defined method in the Table Adapter that queries data from SQL server.

[image]

This is schema of the table that I'm querying data from

[image]

The method works fine without an issue but when I insert the date value from `DateTimePicker` to its parameter , it literally throws "Conversion failed " exception. The format of date is converted to "yyyy/MM/dd" to store it in the table with DATE data type column.

This is db fiddle for more information about the tables and data types that I'm storing [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a170e1036dc5715d2362fa9f1dd139bb)

How can I send date from C# to SQL Server in "yyyy/MM/dd" format?
Is there any workaround for this kind of issue?

Comment: could you please explain why you do not want to send Date in the standard format ('YYYYMMDD')

Comment: *Stop* trying to use strings. ADO.Net is perfectly capable of converting .NET DateTimes into SQL Server's `datetime2` and related types. So change all of your code to use *appropriate* types (and if you're building SQL queries via string concatenation, stop doing that too and use parameters) and suddenly you don't have to fiddle about with formatting, which is *only* a concern when converting from and to strings.

Comment: What type are those parameters on the `GetAvailableRooms` method? What type are the `check_in` and `check_out` columns in the database?

Comment: Don't post pictures of code. Post it as text, formatted as code. If we want to test your code or edit it, we have to retype it from scratch, instead of being able to copy and paste.

Comment: If the database columns are type `date` then I would expect the method parameters to be type `DateTime`. Instead of `string checkIn = dtPicker_checkIn.Value.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd");`, you should probably have `DateTime checkIn = dtPicker_checkIn.Value.Date;`. If the parameters are type `string` for some reason then I would think it should be `string checkIn = dtPicker_checkIn.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");`.

Comment: @ The method in table adapter only accept string data type for its parameters even though it is going to compare with Date data type and I don't know why it only accepts string and not Date or DateTime . Is there any way to make the data type of the parameters in Table Adapter methods to a specific data type instead of using string?

Comment: @Sergey I added sample data of the table . Please check it out .

Comment: If you really are forced to use strings by the component, send them to SQL in YYYYMMDD format As Sergey suggested. It's unambiguous.

Comment: When I add a method using the TableAdapter query wizard (in VS2022) and working against a datetime column the system correctly sets the type of the parameter on the autogenerated method to datetime. So it looks like the tools try to do the right thing (although I admit I don't use these tools often). What version of VS are you using?

Comment: @allmhuran I tried sending data in " YYYYMMDD" format and it works in SSMS but when I send it via Table Adapter method, it just throws tha same exact exception ( "Conversion failed...") . Also, when I test the table adapter method alone , it works fine but if I used the method in my C# code, the exeception happens . Do you have any idea of how this is happening ?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I'm using VS 2022 version 4.8.

Comment: Change your table adapter to accept a `DateTime`, better yet don't use an adapter at all, it's unnecessary. Just use `SqlCommand`

Answer (score 1):

While inserting date, you can use the following:

```
commmand.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
```

@Date is a parameter. change it to your parameter name.

Comment: But I am using method from Table Adapter . So, I can't add parameters like this. It could only be something like " GetAvailableRooms(date checkIn, date checkOut) " and the method is accepting string instead of Date data type.